# Howto ignore specific string interpolation and use plain text in JavaScript template literals?

Tags: javascript, template-literals

I have to setup a config file by code and pass in some variables

```
const confEntry = String.raw`
[${internal}]
...
user = bg${internal}
auth_user = bg${internal}
...
secret = ${password}
...
from_sip_src_setting=from_display,sip_from_user_setting=${account_username}
...
`;
```

when it comes to

`from_sip_src_setting=from_display,sip_from_user_setting=${account_username}`

I don't want to pass in a variable. `=${account_username}` should be written as plain text. Obviously I get the error

> account_username is not defined

How can I ignore this and write plain text for this specific part?

Comment: Escape the curly braces like `$\{account_username\}`

Comment: yes, this works but then it writes `$\{account_username\}` to the file instead of `${account_username}`. Can I fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to keep `${}` in your final string, you can escape either the dollar sign, the curly braces or both using a backslash `\`, this will break the `${}` pattern and it will be treated as regular text:

```js
const world = 'world';
console.log(`\${hello} $\{world\} \$\{hello\} ${world}`);
```

> However, since `String.raw` escapes everything, you cannot use that trick.

But, using the above trick, you could generate the `${str}` string using an inner template string like this:

```js
const world = 'world';
const raw = x => `\${${x}}`;
console.log(String.raw`${raw('hello')} ${world}`);
```

Or simply:

```js
const world = 'world';
const raw = x => '${' + x + '}';
console.log(String.raw`${raw('hello')} ${world}`);
```

Comment: when I usehttps://jsfiddle.net/2q46gtbx/1/ it works fine. When I use https://jsfiddle.net/v52pkdhg/ for my whole config it doesn't

Comment: @MHComputech, I added an example which works with String.raw

Answer (score 1):

You will need to escape the curly braces in order for it not to be interpreted as a string literal

So instead of `${account_username}` ist would be `$\{account_username\}`

Comment: Thanks for your help but this is not working correctly. The escape characters get written down too https://jsfiddle.net/v52pkdhg/1/

Answer (score 0):

> [***String.raw***](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/raw) used to get the raw string form of template
>   strings, that is, substitutions (e.g. ${foo}) are processed, but
>   escapes (e.g. \n) are not.

String.raw do not process your escapes.

```js
let a = String.raw`hello\nhow are you`
let b = `hello\nhow are you`

console.log(a) //raw string output
console.log(b) // template string output
```